# Button image stretching

Tags: ios, image, button

I am having a problem with the button image. I have a green background and an icon. The problem is that on larger screens the image stretches due to the button also stretch to the size of the screen.

I found several other topics they were talking about something, but none of them helped me solve this problem.

The next best picture explains the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your button to look like the 3rd image, you will have to use an image of that size and resolution.

Alternatively, you can set contentMode on your `UIButton`'s imageView object. Use this line of code in your `viewDidLoad` function

```
button.imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

When your constraints increase the size of your button, the image used inside it will abide by the contentMode property set. Using those you can stretch it, which it's doing right now, or you can keep the aspect ratio, in which case it will show empty space on sides.

Comment: I'm using the button background is UIColor, and the button image centered is a icon phone, the icon phone is middle of size button

Comment: @Gian What color is your UIColor background?

Comment: the button is only green. The background color is green, the others colors it is not the button

Comment: @Gian Are you setting the image in Storyboard?

Comment: Yes in the storyboard

Comment: In your `viewDidLoad` use this line `button.imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit`

Comment: It worked. Could place as a response to that I scored as correct?

Comment: @Gian Updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Play around with the content mode settings, try 'Aspect fit' instead of the currently selected.

Answer (score 0):

It look like your constraints doesn't take on consideration the size of the asset.

You should set a Width and a Heigth constraints to your image asset.

Comment: I'm considering that you use the same image on all resolutions, right? In case you have 3 different images, you won't have this problem...

Comment: im using the button background is UIColor, and the button image centered is a icon phone

Comment: @Gian Can you show us some code or how the constraints are placed?